# Schema Based Multitenancy

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I am facing some issues to make the connection to the particular schema on SQL Server because the `setschema` method is deprecated in JDBC API. So please help to get any alternative.

I got following error:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Warning: setSchema is a no-op in this driver version

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't set a schema for a sql-server session. What you can do is define a user with a default schema of the one you want.